# Are there any movie actor/actress turned into porn actor/actress?

Tags: adult-movies

Are there any movie actor/actress turned into porn actor/actress?

Comment: This is way too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many did, most of them did due to lack of work:

[Maitland Ward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitland_Ward): she was in *Boy Meets World* and *The Bold and the Beautiful* but from 2019, she is working in pornographic films.

> She told In Touch Weekly: "They asked me to be a part of this, and I thought, 'I never knew there was anything in adults or porn or whatever that was this well done'.

> "I read the script, and I was like, 'This is really, really well written. This has so many themes in this and just my character is so different than anything I have portrayed before'." - [mirror.co.uk](https://www.mirror.co.uk/3am/celebrity-news/disney-actress-became-porn-star-21128407)

[Jaimee Foxworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaimee_Foxworth): Child actor from *Family Matters* did work in pornographic films from 2000-2002, she told her reasons:

> “Work stopped coming in and my family fell on hard times, so I started doing things that probably weren’t the best decision for a young woman,” - [lifeandstylemag](https://www.lifeandstylemag.com/posts/celebs-who-are-porn-stars-now-113140/)

Then there are some edge cases too like [Dustin Diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dustin_Diamond) who only gave his face in pornographic film, rest was body double.

Few more names are present in [cheatsheet](https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/forgotten-celebrities-later-did-porn.html/) and [lifeandstylemag](https://www.lifeandstylemag.com/posts/celebs-who-are-porn-stars-now-113140/).

Also from Wikipedia: [List of mainstream actors who have appeared in pornographic films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mainstream_actors_who_have_appeared_in_pornographic_films)